# Why are these questions on hold?

Tags: discussion

I refer to my questions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850483/difference-between-the-java-tutorial-and-java-a-beginners-guide

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867339/how-is-the-java-tutorials-book-different-from-the-same-thing-on-oracles-website

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Exactly how do those questions match this description? I'm not asking for a recommendation, nor asking you to find them. They are there, I already identified the specific items I'm asking about.

I am describing my problem in there: It's not "which one do you THINK would be better for me?" It is "what do you know about the contents of these books?" I'm asking for factual information there. I want to know those information before I decide - on my own, not from others' opinions - which option to choose.

My preferred way of learning is through text, and I prefer the academic style of textbooks which give good coverage of all areas of a domain or all features of a language: Not just for what my immediate job or project needs but also to be aware of the whole. I don't "pick something to do and see what you don't know while doing it", I prefer to complement the book with a project, and put it to practice applying each thing I learn from the book in a non-toy problem. Basically, I learn through books.

So, I'm going to be asking a lot of questions about books I find, and I'm not looking for opinions either. I can go to Amazon for reviews. But I want to know facts about their contents from people who have already read them before I decide for myself what to get.

So please, tell me how I am supposed to modify my current and future questions to be "on-topic", because from my point of view the reason given doesn't match my questions at all. What am I not seeing? And if this forum isn't ever going to entertain such questions whether they are opinion questions or not, then pray tell, where should I go to ask them? Stackoverflow is the only web resource I know of for software development. I don't want to use Google to find other places: Google doesn't review or recommend communities.

Comment: The other common applicable close options are _too broad_ or _primariliy opinion based_, pick one.

Comment: As I said, it's not opinion based. "How is A different from B" isn't answered with an opinion piece, it's answered with a factual comparison. The question isn't "Who should read A and who should read B?" And how in the world is "What is inside A" broad?

Comment: @thegreatjedi `Which book should I be using?` That's not a question that can be objectively answered.  It's asking for opinions, flat out.

Comment: @thegreatjedi Sorry I was in TL;DR; mode didn't even read your questions. But these are the most likely reasons, and if 5 people agree these are right most of the times,

Comment: @Servy The first part of the question, which I emphasized as the main question, is the difference between the two, which I had pointed out appeared to look the same based on the Table of Contents, so I want to know how exactly the inside is different. Asking which book I should be using is secondary and to be based on those factual differences. It's not opinion.

Comment: @thegreatjedi Saying that it's not an opinion doesn't make it not an opinion.  It's *absolutely* an opinion.  If that's not the question that you want to ask *then don't ask that*.  As for the first question, asking for a completely list of every single difference between two entire books is *obviously* too broad, I don't know how you could possibly think it wouldn't be.

Comment: @Servy I'm not asking for a page by page difference. I was asking "I can't see the difference, do you know what the difference is?" For example, if I asked that about two airplanes, you CAN break down the difference screw by screw, but you won't. You'd just say "I know that one's faster/older/holds more fuel etc." because that's the first type of answer that comes to mind. And it's not an opinion nor is it broad. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: @thegreatjedi So you want people's **opinions** about what differences they *suspect* you actually care about, rather than an objective list of facts about the two books, because the actual objective list of facts is way too broad and you couldn't be bothered to even look through it?

Comment: @Servy I looked through the table of contents. It looks the same to me, chapter by chapter. I want to know what is inside the books: Does it say who its intended audience is? Does that differ? Or, for the same topic, does it go through it differently? How?

Comment: @thegreatjedi If there is one *specific* aspect for which you want to know how the two differ, for which the answer to such a question can be objectively stated as correct or incorrect, and given in a paragraph or two, then that would be an appropriate question.  Name *all* the differences does not meet those criteria.

Comment: Yeah, this is why questions like these are off topic.  FYI, amazon reviews are the best place to get people's opinions on books.  And it never hurts to read two books if they turn out to be not that dissimilar in the end.

Answer (score 20):

The fact that you don't know where else to go to ask these questions, and can't be bothered to even look anywhere else besides SO, doesn't make these questions on topic on SO, nor are the questions going to remain open just because you can't be bothered to find a site where the questions are actually appropriate.

Both questions are *way* too broad, both are asking for opinions, neither is actually asking about a programming problem...they're *completely* off topic for SO.  While the given close reason isn't the close reason I'd use, it's just not worth re-closing the question just to change the close reason.  You can even read them as recommendation questions, so it's not an *inapplicable* reason, it's just the less applicable reason.

Comment: I didn't say I did not search around. I said the results aren't good: All I found are places like codeacademy, udemy etc., Amazon, and all sorts of forums I've never heard of. They either completely don't cater to the learning style I'm looking for, or I'm not certain which one is the right place to ask because I've never heard of them.

Comment: @thegreatjedi So you're refusing to learn about any other sites because you don't already know everything about them?  So what, you just never learn anything ever, because you only spend time learning about things you already know?  Rather than ignoring every site you've never used, learn to use a site you haven't, if none of the sites you know does what you need.

Comment: I don't know which one to go to. Those "sites" I don't know are all forums. I haven't seen people use them before, nor have I had them recommended to me. So I can't be certain if their recommendations would be reliable. It's not like I can compare or get reviews of forum communities from Google. So I'm asking here, from people that I do know can be relied on.

Comment: @thegreatjedi But the questions don't belong here.  No matter how reliable the corner cafe is at making a great cup of coffee in the morning, it's a terrible place to go to have your car's oil changed.  Just because a place of business is really good at doing what it's set out to do doesn't mean you go to them to do literally everything you ever want done.  You simply go to that place when you want the services that *they actually offer*.  Getting book recommendations isn't a service SO offers.  If you don't trust any other site to help you, then I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: Sorry, it's not that I didn't try. It just didn't work. Hundreds of views but no answers. I've went through the first couple pages of Google's results before. That's why I gave up that approach. It's why I keep coming back to Stackoverflow even though I know how easily these questions become closed. Because people here are the only one who respond. And if this is going to keep happening, my only recourse is to come here to meta and figure out how to fix it. Maybe it didn't sound like I tried up there, but when I do it simply doesn't work out.

Comment: @thegreatjedi Frankly that doesn't matter.  No matter how much you complain to the coffee shop owners about how all the garages in town suck and can't even do a simple oil change, the coffee shop still isn't going to change your oil for you.  It's just not what they're there for, no matter how bad other people are at fulfilling that service.  Continuing to badger the coffee shop owner over and over again to change your oil, regardless of how many times they refuse, isn't going to result in you getting your oil changed.

Comment: That's the Zen of Moderation, right up here ^^^ . . . . @thegreatjedi, `Because people here are the only one who respond` --> this, exactly this, you just need to learn [ask] and what's [On-Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), after that, no oil, no coffee, just answers ;)

Comment: @thegreatjedi: “I ask off-topic questions here because people here are the only ones who respond.” Analogy: “I dump my rubbish in this forest because it’s the only place not already filled with rubbish.” If everyone does what you do, this site will become exactly like other sites.

Answer (score 8):

> So, I'm going to be asking a lot of questions about books I find, and I'm not looking for opinions either.

These two statements are *strongly* contradictory.  Everyone has a stance on books, and everyone that thinks that there is a single "best" book has only added more opinions to the discussion.

> But I want to know facts about their contents from people who have already read them before I decide for myself what to get.

...So you want a book review.  Most every book seller will allow their customers to review it, including those from O'Reilly and Apress.

> So please, tell me how I am supposed to modify my current and future questions to be "on-topic", because from my point of view the reason given doesn't match my questions at all. What am I not seeing?

Your current questions aren't suitable for the site, because they're explicitly looking for discussion on a third-party resource.  That is explicitly not allowed here.

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

> And if this forum isn't ever going to entertain such questions whether they are opinion questions or not, then pray tell, where should I go to ask them?

Four things:

1. This ***isn't*** a forum.
2. Consider reading the reviews of the book to see if it meshes well with what you expect.  Everyone learns differently, but unless you buy the book, reviews are the best thing for you to go off of.
3. All we're saying is that you can't ask them on Stack Overflow because they're opinionated and will lead to opinionated discussions.  Sometimes, the best thing to do in this scenario is to buy and read the book and draw your own conclusions.
4. Actually, you should just buy the book.  Nothing will inform you about the book's contents and material better than first-hand experience.

Comment: Don't you understand the *investment* it requires to read a book???  You can't just go, willy nilly, out and start reading.  You have to **prepare**.  It sometimes takes me months before I can sit down and read a menu.  Can you comprehend the time it takes for me to prepare to read a ***book***?  You're being completely unreasonable, and you should be ashamed of yourself.

Comment: “Actually, you should just buy the book.” Why not the whole bookstore? Do you want OP to read every book only to find out which books he shouldn’t read? That would defeat the purpose. You can’t read every beginner’s book because you can’t enter the same river twice. You can’t *unread* a book. You’re a beginner only once.